# Is it possible to get a time for state transition for an Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm accessing EC2 with the aws-sdk for Ruby. I have an array of instances from describe_instances().

This provides me with the state of the instances and even a state transition reason. But how can I get a time for the state transition?

Edit
So I have:

```
client=Aws::EC2::Client()  
resp =client.describe_instances({ filters })
```

and I would need

```
resp.reservations[0].instances[0].state_transition_time #=> Time
```

similar to

```
resp.reservations[0].instances[0].state_transition_reason #=> String
```

Answer (score 0):

This information is not available via the Amazon EC2 API at this time. The `aws-sdk` gem returns all of the information available from the DescribeInstances operation as documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html

Answer (score 0):

The State Transition Reason is not always populated with a date and time and may not even be populated at all per the documentation. I have not found any hints in the documentation that specify the conditions in which you DO get a date/time, but in my experience, the date/time are present in the State Transition Reason for between 30 and 90 days. After that, the reason seems to persist, but the date is dropped from the string.

All of the documentation that I can find is listed here:

- [Attribute Definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_StateReason.html)
- [EC2 API - Ruby](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/EC2/Client.html#describe_instances-instance_method)